# RabbitMQ MQTT over Websockets security concern

Tags: authentication, websocket, rabbitmq, mqtt, mqtt-over-websockets

My question is about **MQTT support of RabbitMQ**. After enabling the required plugins, RabbitMQ supports both MQTT and MQTT over Websockets. For server-side connections MQTT user/pass authentication is ok, because it works under the hood and we are able to secure these credentials with enterprise-wide tools. However, when it comes to utilize Websockets support and create connections from frontend javascript, we need to include username/password in our frontend. It would be as easy as opening up the developer console of a browser to get these credentials.

What is the **best-practice** for securing these connections? What alternatives do we have here? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Generate short lived credentials for each session and load them as a REST request over HTTPS combined with tight ACLs that only allow access to the topics needed for the web app.